# How to export a date and time column properly from SPSS into csv

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, spss

I am struggling with SPSS and would greatly appreciate your help.

I have a column with dates and times of type "Date" in an SPSS file (version 22), such as:

> 5-Aug-2014 13:12:00

I would like to export it into csv, but all I get in the resultant csv file is:

> 8/5/2014

How do you set up SPSS so that you get the time as well as date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the variable into a string before exporting it.