# SPSS syntax to convert all date variables into strings

Tags: variables, type-conversion, spss

Could someone suggest SPSS syntax that would (1) find all date variables and then (2) convert them into strings, e.g. with the following command:

```
alter type dateVariable (a20).
```

That would be very helpful for exporting data into R (because I need to [convert dates to strings first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775209/how-to-export-a-date-and-time-column-properly-from-spss-into-csv)).

I will hugely appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALTER TYPE can select variables based on their format and convert to strings, so just specify the input and output formats without a list of variable names.

Comment: Thanks, so an example would be the following command: 

`alter type ALL (DATETIMEw=a20).`